# Apache Virtual Host time based

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Is it possible to make a virtual host available based on time?

Can the configuration be done within the httpd.conf file directly without the use of external commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard of a module doing that (well it has been proved false anyway), but of course you can have your virtual host settings in its own conf file, and then set a cron job to rename it(so it won't get loaded) and trigger a reload of apache's configuration...no downtime.

Answer (score 2):

You may get some mileage out of [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this as the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive has access to time and date variables `TIME_YEAR`, `TIME_MON`, `TIME_DAY`, `TIME_HOUR`, `TIME_MIN`, `TIME_SEC`, `TIME_WDAY`, and `TIME`.

So you could do something like for example

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >16
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <22
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /1622.html
```

or whatever you want really.